# IndexError: tuple index out of range. Call a list class variable inside a class function

Tags: python, list, range, tuples, overwrite

I am getting

> IndexError: tuple index out of range

on my script that contains this:

```
def bump_detector(self, array):

    for i in range(len(array)):
        if (array[i+1]-array[i])>0.3:   
            DoorDetector.__bumps.append(i+1)

        if (array[i]-array[i+1]>0.3):
            DoorDetector.__bumps.append(i)
```

and this call:

```
 def cb(self, data):
    self.bump_detector(data.ranges)
```

in a certain class.
The error pops on this line:

```
if (array[i+1]-array[i])>0.3:
```

data.ranges is a list: ranges[640].
I think I am overwriting the ranges list when I pass it as an argument but I am not sure and I don't know how to fix it

Comment: The problem is when i = 639, i + 1 = 640 with gives the IndexError, assuming the length of array is 640

Comment: The error makes perfekt sense. You iterate i from 0 to len(array) and then check for array[i+1] which will crash for the last item. Example: len(array) is 10, then there is no array[11].

Comment: In a sequence with n elements, there are only n-1 pairs of adjacent elements for you to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, because `range(X)` returns `0 .. X-1`. So in your loop `for i in range(len(array))` on last iteration you get `i` equal to max index in array.

And trying to access `array[i+1]` causes exception.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
for i in range(len(array)):
    if (array[i+1]-array[i]) > 0.3:
```

The last value of `i` will be the last index in `array`, so `i+1` will indeed be out of range. Same problem here FWIW:

```
    if (array[i]-array[i+1] > 0.3):
```

You can solve this by using `range(len(array) -1)` instead or, better, by using `zip()`:

```
 for x, y in zip(array, array[1:]):
     if y - x > 0.3:
        # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

At the last iteration, i = 639 and array[640] does not exist, hence the IndexError.

```
def bump_detector(self, array):
    for i in range(len(array) - 1):  # Add a "-1" here
        if (array[i+1]-array[i])>0.3:   
            DoorDetector.__bumps.append(i+1)
        if (array[i]-array[i+1]>0.3):
            DoorDetector.__bumps.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the loop statement with

```
for i in range(len(array) - 1):
```

It will only iterate through the 0 to n-1. Since the last element will not be compared.